# Using AJAX to get an SQL WHERE query into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, where-clause

I am trying to pass a javascript variable into an SQL WHERE query and I keep getting null in return.

On-click of a button, the ***buttonClick*** function is ran:

```
<script>
    var var1;
    function buttonClick(elem){
        var1 = elem.src              //this gets the url from the element
        var path = var1.slice(48);   //this cuts the url to img/art/9/1.jpg
        ajax = theAjax(path);
        ajax.done(processData);
        ajax.fail(function(){alert("Failure");});
    }

    function theAjax(path){
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'info.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {path: path},
        });
    }

    function processData(response_in){
        var response = JSON.parse(response_in);
        console.log(response);
    }
</script>
```

Here is the code stored in the **info.php** file:

```
<?php
    $path = $_POST['path'];

    $result3 = mysqli_query("SELECT itemName from images WHERE imgPath='$path'");
    $json = json_encode($result3);

    echo $json
?>
```

As you can see, once I click the button, the **buttonClick()** function is ran and a variable stores the image path or src. That **path** variable is send to **theAjax()** function where it is passed to the **info.php** page. In the **info.php** page, the SQL WHERE query is ran and returned to the **processData()** function to be parsed and printed in the developer console. The value printed shows ***null***.

Below is a picture of what I am trying to get from the database:
[image]

Comment: Looking into your code, not able to see database connections. You need to connect your database first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Check that `path` is correct or not? you can check inside jquery using `console.log(path);` or at PHP end by using `print_r($_POST['path']);`

***2.Your Php code missed connection object as well as record fetching code.***

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['path'])){
        $path = $_POST['path'];

        $conn = mysqli_connect ('provide hostname here','provide username here','provide password here','provide dbname here') or die(mysqli_connect_error());

        $result3 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT itemName from images WHERE imgPath='$path'");

        $result = []; //create an array

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
             $result[] = $row; //assign records to array
        }
        $json = json_encode($result); //encode response
        echo $json; //send response to ajax
    }

?>
```

***Note:-*** this PHP query code is wide-open for `SQL INJECTION`. So try to use `prepared statements` of `mysqli_*` Or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query()` required 1st parameter as connection object.

```
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT itemName from images WHERE imgPath='$path'"); // pass your connection object here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you're trying to encode a database resource.

Try adjusting your PHP to look like the following:

```
<?php
    $path = $_POST['path'];

    $result3 = mysqli_query("SELECT itemName from images WHERE imgPath='$path'");
    $return_data = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
        $return_data[] = $row;
    }
    $json = json_encode($return_data);

    echo $json
?>
```

Comment: This returned an empty array